# C : infinite loop in the input

Tags: c, loops, stdin

Here's my function and the problem is 
It never stops getting the input, in the command line.
I can't figure out where is the proper line to place a `return 0`.

```
int my_rot13(int c) {
    if ('a' <= tolower(c) && tolower(c) <= 'z')
        return tolower(c)+13 <= 'z' ? c+13 : c-13;
    return c;
}

int main() {

  int k, c;
  char *p;

  if (argc < 2) {
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
      putchar(my_rot13(c));  
    }
    return 0; 
  }

  for (k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
    for (p = argv[k]; *p != '\0'; p++) {
      putchar(my_rot13(*p));
    }
    putchar(' ');
  }
  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```

If I pass in the standard input like `./a.out "hey"`, it works exiting the program.

but when I get into user input mode
I can not get out of this function.

Comment: Press CTRL-D to end the input. (or CTRL-Z if you're on windows)

Comment: Or check for `(c = getc(stdin)) != '\n'` to just accept one line. +1 for a well-formed question with proper code

Comment: Alternatively, check for something else than `EOF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) character to `getc()`, when you are typing the input in manually. You can do this on Linux with Ctrl-D, and on Windows with Ctrl-Z. Another option would be for you to test against a newline ('\n').

Answer (score 0):

If you're capturing from standard input, then use `'\n'` instead of `EOF`.